# Do I need to write a trigger for such a simple constraint?

Tags: oracle10g, constraints

I really had a hard time knowing what words to put into the title of my question, as I am not especially sure if there is a database pattern related to my problem.  I will try to simplify matters as much as possible to get directly to the heart of the issue.

Suppose I have some tables. 
The first one is a list of widget types:

```
create table widget_types (
    widget_type_id number(7,0) primary key,
    description varchar2(50)
);
```

The next one contains icons:

```
create table icons (
    icon_id number(7,0) primary key,
    picture blob
);
```

Even though the users get to select their preferred widget, there is a predefined subset of widgets that they can choose from for each widget type.

```
create table icon_associations (
    widget_type_id number(7,0) references widget_types,
    icon_id number(7,0) references icons,
    primary key (widget_type_id, icon_id)
);

create table icon_prefs (
    user_id number(7,0) references users,
    widget_type_id number(7,0),
    icon_id number(7,0),
    primary key (user_id, widget_type_id),
    foreign key (widget_type_id, icon_id) references icon_associations
);
```

Pretty simple so far.

Let us now assume that if we are displaying an icon to a user who has not set up his preferences, we choose one of the appropriate images associated with the current widget. I'd like to specify the preferred icon to display in such a case, and here's where I run into my problem:

```
alter table icon_associations 
    add ( is_preferred char(1) check( is_preferred in ('y','n') ) )
;
```

I do not see how I can enforce that for each widget_type there is one, and only one, row having is_preferred set to 'y'.

I know that in MySQL, I am able to write a subquery in my check constraint to quickly resolve this issue.  This is not possible with Oracle.

Is my mistake that this column has no business being in the icon_associations table?  If not where should it go?  Is this a case where, in Oracle, the constraint can only be handled with a trigger?

I ask only because I'd like to go the constraint route if at all possible.

Thanks so much for your help,
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way that I believe solves your issue is to have another table called

```
icon_default_associations (widget_type_id, icon_id)
```

and simply make `(widget_type_id, icon_id)` obey a UNIQUE constraint (or make it the primary key).

I think you're overloading the purpose of icon_associations if you do it the way you're attempting.

Comment: But this only prevents the creation of more than one preferred icon (in cases where an icon is specified). I can still specify icons without marking any as preferred.

Comment: As far as the purpose of icon_associations goes, I have had that feeling as well. But neither am I convinced that I have overextended it either.

Comment: If you want to ensure all icons have 1 and only 1 preference, then I think it's better to just add another column to the icons table called "default_widget_association" and make it NOT NULL.  You can then do away with my suggested icon_default_associations table.  You may also want to rename the icon_associations table.

Comment: Since in my case, it turns out that having a 1:0..1 solution is not too bad, I used this solution.  If I needed the 1:1 solution, I would have to create a cyclical FK with deferred constraints.  Seems like too much hassle for now.

Answer (score 0):

If the default icons don't change, could you just make sure that the default icon goes into the icon_associations table first?

That way, you are always guaranteed ONE and ONLY one default icon, it will never go away as long as there ARE icons, and you don't need to futz with an is_preferred column, or its constraints and triggers.

It would also be easy to retrieve the default icon:

```
SELECT * from icon_associations WHERE ID=MIN(ID)
```

The downside is that changing the default icon would require a little bit of work, but if that never happens, this solves your is_preferred column issue.

Comment: It is a clever solution. I am not lucky enough to have such a convenient out. (my problem is more complex than the icon problem, but they are similar). It does make me think that I could have a numerical rank column, rather than the binary preference value. It would mean that I don't have to defer constraints on update. But it would make selecting the best ranked icon more difficult.